# How to fix 'processorListFile' does not exist. when building appbundle in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception**
Firebase admob worked okay in my Flutter app but when running build appbundle --release and I got error as follows below:

**Error Output**

```
PS D:\Projects\new\kjv_bible> flutter build appbundle --release
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':firebase_core_web:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> File 'D:\Projects\new\kjv_bible\build\firebase_core_web\intermediates\annotation_processor_list\release\annotationProcessors.json' specified for property 'processorListFile' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 26s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       209.8s (!)
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

**Flutter doctor**
Run `flutter doctor` and paste the output below:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (4 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ljoe0\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I added Firebase_core in the pubspec.yaml and still got the same error.
I googled for this error for hours but to no avail.
Please what could go wrong with this error?

Comment: It is now fixed by deleted the .gradle directory in the project root folder. Thanks!!

Comment: worked for me as well, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the op himself stated in comments, deleting `.gradle` folder fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the folder called `.gradle`
found inside $/android/.grade